# How do I connect to a UDP port in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, logging, udp

Like everyone else, I can say "I've tried everything!" I kind of did. I looked all over StackOverflow, and tried all the answers, but got nothing. Anyways, I am jetting to at least get some code printed by Python before I get even further in developing this.

I want to receive UDP packets from my Garry's Mod server (logaddress_add MyIP:7131), and I don't seem to be receiving any of those packets. It's most likely not a router firewall problem, as I can use HLSW on my other computer. I have used Wireshark, and didn't see any data from my server's IP. I used the Python interpreter / [made some code](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket-example) (although example was TCP) to see if I got any data--to make sure Wireshark wasn't doing anything wrong--and nothing came to it either. Am I doing something silly?

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7131))

sock.settimeout(10)
sock.recv(1024)
```

Edit : I was doing some testing with HLSW, and found out it seems to be doing some kind of magic. When you try to logaddress_add the certain Port that is not HLSW (say 7135), it won't do anything. Wireshark won't do anything at all. Doesn't show any logs, anything. But, when you change HLSW to use the port that you just added (7135), Wireshark suddenly gets a flow of data, including the console data that I am jetting for. Is it some kind of configuration HLSW is changing?

Comment: If Wireshark doesn't detect any packets from the server, you're probably not getting any packets from the server. Using a socket instead of libpcap to do the detection isn't going to change that. I'd advise you to concentrate on figuring out why the packets aren't making it across the network. Don't do anything with Python until you can verify (with Wireshark) that the packets are getting through.

Comment: If the packets do get through (for the future) will that Python code suffice and get data?

Comment: i think some kind of "udp hole punching" is being done.

Answer (score 11):

(Not quite an answer, but a diagnostic path that might lead to an answer. Sometimes it helps just to know that it actually worked for someone else.)

I've entered the above into a Python console, and then typed the code below into another Python console:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto('hello', 0, ('127.0.0.1', 7131))
```

The message popped out on the original console. I repeated the experiment from another machine, using a '192.168...' address instead, and it popped out again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7131)) instead of bind.